# Can someone help me with my Goldbach code ? When i call the function and then put 1,000,000 it seems not to spit out any output i dont know why?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to reach 1,000,000 and for some reason it doesn't give me the output for 1,000,000, I don't know what i am doing wrong. Every time i put a small number like 500 it would give me the correct output but as soon as i put 999,999 or 1,000,000 it just doesn't give out any output and when i do a keyboard interruption it says it stopped at break but I need that break in order for the values to only repeat once.

```
bachslst=[]
primeslst=[]
q=[]
newlst=[]
z=[]

def goldbach(limit):
    primes = dict()
    for i in range(2, limit+1):
        primes[i] = True
    for i in primes:
        factors = range(i, limit+1, i)
        for f in factors[1:]:
            primes[f] = False
    for i in primes:
        if primes[i]==True:
            z.append(i)     
    for num in range(4,limit+1,2):
        for k in range(len(z)):
            for j in z:
                if (k + j ) == num :
                    x=(str(k),str(j))
                    q.append(x)
                    newlst.append([x,[num]])
                break
        bachslst.append(num)   
    print(bachslst,'\n')      
    return newlst
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. You need to read [mcve] and [help]. As it stands, its very hard for us to help you.

Comment: i posted a picture of it so everyone can see it better

Comment: If you had read the link I gave you, you would know why that's frowned on. It makes it hard for people to copy and paste the code so they can run it, and it makes it so search engines can't find it.

Comment: How long did you wait for output?

Comment: at least three min

Comment: @arewm sorry i forgot to add the list before i added the def fuction: bachslst=[]
primeslst=[]
q=[]
newlst=[]
z=[]

Comment: @takendarkk it suppose to take at least 3 min

Comment: It is a slow algorithm. If you try to determine `goldbach(999999)`, `len(z)=78498`. All of the iterations will just take time. I have not looked at the implementation, but if you want it to be faster, you can try to optimize/reduce the loops. Maybe if you include some memoization, it would speed everything up. If you add some print statements in there, you will see that the calculation is still chugging.

Comment: @arewm ya i never programmed in my life and this is my first time programing in python, so im pretty new to all of this.  So is it possible for me to get up to goldbach(1000000)? With my code?

Comment: @moz, yes. eventually.

Comment: @arewm is it possible to post the edited version of the code?

Comment: @moz I have not edited the code, I just ran it as-is. It looks like 1000 iterations of for num in range() takes about 6 seconds on my computer, so it should complete in about 1.5 hours. It looks like you are doing a lot more work than you need to. Try looking at codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/99161/… for help.

Answer (score 0):

The break that is referred to is not the break in the code, it is the break caused by the keyboard interrupt.

If you want to get your result in less than 1.5 hours, try to reduce the amount of computing that you are doing. There are many implementations for testing the Goldbach Conjecture if you do a search. Some are in other languages, but you can still use them to influence your algorithm.

I have not looked at it, but here is another implementation in Python: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/99161/function-to-find-two-prime-numbers-that-sum-up-to-a-given-even-number

Comment: @arewn ya i try running it but its only giving me some errors

Comment: I would suggest looking at other locations for sample implementations. It seems like it is a reasonably common teaching tool in many languages. Even if you have to port code from a different language to Python, it is a learning experience. Your code eventually returned when I let it run, but with a result that did not seem correct. So as I said, I would take another look at the implementation.

Comment: But to answer the original question, your code is working 'in a sense.' It is completing and not hanging. The break message you got was not related to your code.